# How do I configure MIDI in Reaper

Tags: midi, reaper

I have a keyboard (set to MIDI channel 1) plugged into the MIDI In on my M-Audio Profire 2626.

I have added a track to my project and selected MIDI Input->Profire 2626 MIDI->All Channels as my input.  I selected Monitor Input.  I added ReaControlMIDI to my effects, checked Enable, loaded GM.reabank, selected General MIDI and Acoustic Grand Piano.

When I play the keyboard, the MIDI level meter on the track moves, but I get no sound.  I get the same results with the virtual keyboard.

I switched the effect to reaSynth and it works fine, showing both the MIDI level meter and the audio level meter.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it the MIDI level meter or the audio one?  IIRC they are separate, and you want to make sure you are getting some kind of audio out of your plugin.

Comment: It is the MIDI level meter.  I have edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the IO button on the track brings up the routing for the track.  I had not selected anything for MIDI Hardware output.  Selecting the GM wavetable synth from my sound card fixed the problem.

For an excellent guide on getting started with Reaper and MIDI [look here](http://stash.reaper.fm/7453/Art_of_Reabanks.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 0):

There is a little button on the bottom right of the track (with a speaker looking left) "Input". Click it till it becomes green.